# Reading data from a file with missing columns. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

Essentially i have a data file with 8 columns and i want to put each value from each column into an array variable. But the issue is that some values are missing. 
e.g.

```
100 54201.10 49392 9379101 10381.1372
101 5823829        73929   83729.77
```

Where the missing value is spaced by an extra tab or /t space. 
How can i read the values, ignoring the missing data and inputting the correct values into the correct variable once available?

I tried using:

```
infile >> network;
    string val = isNaN(network);
    if (count % 8 == 0) { ID[count / 8] = val; }
    if (count % 8 == 1) { time[count / 8] = val; }
    if (count % 8 == 2) { country_code[count / 8] = val; }
    if (count % 8 == 3) { sms_in[count / 8] = val; }
    if (count % 8 == 4) { sms_out[count / 8] = val; }
    if (count % 8 == 5) { call_in[count / 8] = val; }
    if (count % 8 == 6) { call_out[count / 8] = val; }
    if (count % 8 == 7) { internet[count / 8] = val; }
    count++;
```

Comment: Have you heard `switch`?

Comment: Please also specify the format of files, not being ambiguous on tab and spaces.

Comment: It did help but i dont entirely understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this in C++ is to use getline to get each line.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
...
typedef struct {
    unsigned long id;
    unsigned long timestamp;
    ...
} Record;
std::vector<Record> records;
while (std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
    ...
```

Then use [substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to fill the collection of records.  Assuming your fields are tab delimited and have the numbers left justified, you can then handle the defaulting like this.

```
posTab = s.find_first_of('\t');
records[i].id = posTab == 0
    ? defaultID
    : std::atoi(s.substr(0, posTab).c_str());
```

The index i is the record index, starting with 0.  For float and double precision float numbers, you will need to substitute the appropriate standard numerical parser for std::atoi.

If the data is tab delimited, for each field (of each record) use the find_first_of(posTab + 1, '/t') to find the beginning of each field, starting from the previous position which you can save in posPreviousTab to use as the equality test AND the first substr parameter instead of zeros.

**Notes**

For large data sets and under some conditions, std::list is faster than std::vector.  You can write a test to compare both options for your case.

If you are dealing with big data, you may need higher speed, use char[MAXSIZE] and the equivalent algorithm in C and process on the fly instead of storing every record in memory.